# Windows Service always looking in Windows\System32

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that is currently netcore3.1 (I know, I know). When it runs it always looks for the appsettings.config in the `C:\Windows\System32`

Event Viewer

```
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.19.56402
.NET Core Version: 3.1.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Windows\system32\appsettings.json'.
```

Code

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var logger = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetNonDILogger<Program>();
    try {
        logger.LogDebug("Initialize worker");
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        host.Run();
        logger.LogInformation($"Stopped worker");
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        logger.LogInformation($"Stopped worker because of cancelation");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Stopped worker because of exception");
        throw;
    } finally {
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cfg) => cfg.AddSettings(ctx.HostingEnvironment, args))
                .ConfigureLogging(SetupLogging)
                .ConfigureServices((ctx, sc) => ConfigureServices(sc, ctx.Configuration))
                .UseWindowsService();
        }

        private static void SetupLogging(HostBuilderContext ctx, ILoggingBuilder builder) {
            if (ctx == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ctx));
            }
            if (builder == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }
            _ = builder.ClearProviders()
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
                .AddConfiguration(ctx.Configuration.GetSection("Nlog"))
                .AddNLog(); // Add NLog to the logging pipeline 
        }

        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddSettings(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, IHostEnvironment env, string[] args) {
            if (env == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(env));
            }
            if (args == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
            }
            _ = builder
                .SetBasePath("C:\\Program Files\\My.Worker");
            //.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            //.SetBasePath(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            //.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            //if (args != null) {
            //    _ = builder.AddCommandLine(args);
            //}
            //_ = builder.AddSubstitution();
            return builder;
        }
```

The commented out code are different things I have tried. I works when run as a command line, by the minute I start it as a windows service it fails.

I have also tried adding the service using the content root as per the ms website

````
New-Service -Name "My.Worker" -BinaryPathName "C:\\src\src\My.Worker\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\My.Worker.exe" -DisplayName "My Worker" -StartupType Automatic
New-Service -Name "My.Worker" -BinaryPathName "C:\\src\src\My.Worker\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\My.Worker.exe --contentRoot ""C:\\src\src\My.Worker\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1""" -DisplayName "My Worker" -StartupType Automatic```

Updating netcore is not an option at this moment. Any other suggestions?
````

Comment: Have you tried moving `UseWindowsService()` as the first call, before calling `ConfigureAppConfiguration()`?
I suspect this could be the reason but I haven't tried it myself, you may not even need to call the `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` to set the BasePath because after calling `UseWindowsService()`, the app should just read your appSettings from your app folder, if that is what is intended.

Comment: I have cut the `CreateHostBuilder` down to just the `UseWindowsService()` and it still shows the same error in the Event Viewer.

Comment: After digging into some dependencies, I found that it was referencing the CurrentDirectory which was the issue.